# Using a macro for table alignment

Tags: tables, macros, expansion

I am trying to use a macro to define the alignment of a table as shown below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\def\align{|l|c|}
\begin{tabular}{\align}
1 & 2 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

However when I do this I get a message message that seems to indicate that \align is not a valid alignment and 'c' is used instead. It must have to do with the timing of the expansion. How do I get this to work right?

Comment: The actual error message is:
! Package array Error:  Illegal pream-token (\align): `c' used.

Comment: Do you really need `array` package? In basic LaTeX there are no errors during compilation.

Comment: This will raise an error only if the `array` package is loaded. In that case you can do `\newcolumntype{\foo}{|l|c|}` (not `\align`, because this will conflict with `amsmath`, once you load it).

Comment: I actually using this with longtable and in a macro, but I tried to come up with a simple example that had the same problem.

Comment: @egreg in the actual latex code I am building I do not use align as the defined value.

Answer (score 3):

The posted example is completely misleading and runs without error.

If the `array` package is used, then macros in the alignment are not expanded, and `\newcolumntype` can be used for abbreviated column alignment constructs.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\newcolumntype{a}{|l|c|}
\begin{tabular}{a}
1 & 2 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes. This was my mistake. I used a class (not article) which automatically included array. Thanks for the clarification on this.